# Flutter : PaginatedDataTable is it possible to fetch the page now?

Tags: flutter, paginateddatatable

How do I get the page information currently being viewed from'PaginatedDataTable'?

This is example code.

```
new PaginatedDataTable(
              header: const Text('Nutrition'),
              rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) {
                setState(() {
                  _rowsPerPage = value;
                });
              },
              sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
              sortAscending: _sortAscending,
              onSelectAll: _dessertsDataSource._selectAll,
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                new DataColumn(....
              ],
              source: _dessertsDataSource)
```

Comment: I want to get the current page number.

Comment: onPageChanged gives you the index of the page when switches

Comment: @EdwynZN onPageChanged gives the first row's index. It doesn't give you the index of the page.